# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

Tags: javascript

I am receiving Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL in chrome with this code:

```
   var leftMiddleJS = 'function onmouseover() {
        document.getElementById("background").style.marginTop = "-135px"; 
        document.getElementById("background").style.marginLeft = "0px";
        document.getElementById("background").style.width = "760px";
        document.getElementById("background").style.height = "520px";
        document.getElementById("background").style.marginTop = "0";
        document.getElementById("background").style.marginLeft = "0";

        function click() { 
        document.getElementById("outsideContainer").style.marginTop = "0"; 
        document.getElementById("outsideContainer").style.marginLeft = "0"; 
        document.getElementById("outsideContainer").style.width = "300px"; 
        document.getElementById("outsideContainer").style.height = "250px"; 
        document.getElementById("insideContainer").style.marginTop = "-135px"; 
        document.getElementById("insideContainer").style.marginLeft = "0px"; }';
```

What is the problem with the code?

Comment: Its saying is on the first line

Comment: Missing `}` after `document.getElementById("background").style.marginLeft = "0";`

Comment: what are you doing with quote in function declration `'function` onmouseover()

Comment: Don't do that.  You should not store code in a string.

Comment: The double function in a variable makes no sense.

Comment: What's this suppose to be btw?

Comment: Also you should not ask the DOM for one an the same element all the time, store its reference in a variable once and use it instead.

Comment: Use ` \ ` to concatenate lines.

Comment: It is positioning for an HTML5 inbanner video. It starts with the size 300x250 and animates to 760x520. I am positioning it left middle so it animates right top. Any other suggestions on doing so? I also have a rightmiddle and righttop and i want it to animate left

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to assign a string that spans multiple lines - use \ string continuation:

```
var leftMiddleJS = 'function onmouseover() { \
        document.getElementById("background").style.marginTop = "-135px";  \
        document.getElementById("background").style.marginLeft = "0px"; \
        document.getElementById("background").style.width = "760px"; \
        document.getElementById("background").style.height = "520px"; \
        document.getElementById("background").style.marginTop = "0"; \
        document.getElementById("background").style.marginLeft = "0"; \
\
        function click() { \
        document.getElementById("outsideContainer").style.marginTop = "0"; \
        document.getElementById("outsideContainer").style.marginLeft = "0"; \
        document.getElementById("outsideContainer").style.width = "300px"; \
        document.getElementById("outsideContainer").style.height = "250px"; \
        document.getElementById("insideContainer").style.marginTop = "-135px";  \
        document.getElementById("insideContainer").style.marginLeft = "0px"; }';
```